# Allocating memory through malloc-heap(Concatenate string)

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char* concatenate(char a[],char b[])
{
 int length1,length2,i,j,k,l;
 for(int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
  {
   length1=i;
  }
  for(int j=0;b[j]!='\0';j++)
  {
   length2=j;
  }

 char *allocate=(char*)malloc((length1+length2+2)*sizeof(char));    
 for(k=0;k<=length1;k++)
 {
    allocate[k]=a[k];
 }
 allocate[k]=' ';
  for(l=length1+2;l<=(length1+length2+2);l++)
 {
    allocate[l]=b[l-(length1+2)];
 }
 allocate[l]='\0';
 return allocate;
}
int main()
{

 char name1[]="Stack";
 char name2[]="Overflow";
 char* new=concatenate(name1,name2);
 printf("%s\n",new);
 free(new);
 new=0;
 return 0;
}
```

Hi ,I wrote a program to concatenate two strings with the help of malloc concept.I got it correct.But what i didn't get is when i changed the below line

```
char *allocate=(char*)malloc((length1+length2+2)*sizeof(char));
```

to

```
char *allocate=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

the output remain same, how is that even possible,because we need atleast length1+length2+2 bytes to store it with gap?

Comment: unrelated, but `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so you can leave it out.

Comment: C have no bounds-checking. Writing out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior* which makes your program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: You hardly got it "correct" either. Ex: If you passed a zero-length string as `a[]`,  your allocation line would be using a `length1` with *indeterminate* value, as the body of the related for-loop for length saving is never entered because the loop condition kicks you out immediately.  Therefore, the allocation step would invoke *undefined behavior*. Same problem for `length2` It only "works" because both inputs have concrete length > 0.

Comment: You need `length1+length2+4` bytes, since in your code `length1` and `length2` are the indices of the last non-null characters, not the lengths of the strings (they're each one less than the string length).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- Either your runtime environment allocates more memory than necessary, so your "Stack Overflow\0" string fits, but "Stack Overflooooooooooooow\0" would not fit, or
- You are corrupting memory past the block that you allocated, and the C runtime environment does not take notice, because your program is trivial.  However, if your program was slightly more complicated, (say, if you tried to allocate more memory,) you would get an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just tried with input stack overflowwwwwwwwwwww, and yes it shows the output which was not expected.I clearly understood now that without allocating sufficient memory, it would lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *allocate=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

is the same as

```
char *allocate=malloc(1);
```

You allocate exactly *one* byte of memory, this could only hold the empty string, because it only consists of the terminating `0` byte.

C won't stop you if you write beyond the bounds of your object. This is just *undefined behavior*. The outcome could be anything, including a program that *seems* to work. But the next day, or with some other input, it could crash, allow intruders on your system, or even paint your cat green. Just avoid *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I appreciate it.